# How to mutate numeric to factor and keep levels "0" and "1" and not "1" and "2"

Tags: r, r-factor

I have a very large dataset (150 variables, 100 of them are discrete), thus I make a vector (factor_columns) where are names of all 100 columns that I need to change to factors, and then use mutate and as.factor,

```
data <- data %>% mutate_at(factor_columns, as.factor)
```

but then I get for all the binary: Factor, with 2 levels, "0" and "1", but then there are actually "ones" and "twos" instead of "zeroes" and "ones".

[image]

For some reason, R behaves to that sometimes as 0 and 1 and sometimes as 1 and 2.

I have found only ways how to do it for each variable, but with this number of variables, it is not feasible. Is there better way to keep factor levels 0 and 1 (for instance logistic regression within ggplot2 does not work properly because y isnt between 0 and 1, but between 1 and 2).

Providing a part of dataset:

```
"rcp_sex","age","bmi","factor1","factor2","CKD_stage"
"F",36.0739219712526,31,"0","0",NA
"F",26.2778918548939,16.3,"0","0","3a"
"M",38.9541409993155,29.4,"0","0","2"
"F",31.0992470910335,28.3,"0","0",NA
"M",34.6721423682409,28.9,"0","0","3b"
"M",46.6146475017112,26.6,"0","0","3b"
"M",48.7912388774812,23.3,"0","0","3a"
"M",25.2402464065708,27.2,"0","0","2"
"M",48.35318275154,33.5,"0","0","4"
"M",23.4989733059548,31.9,"0","0","3b"
"M",35.3182751540041,26.6,"0","0","2"
"F",34.2368240930869,40.2,"0","0","4"
"F",39.8110882956879,24.3,"0","0","5"
"M",20.6324435318275,30.4,"0","0","2"
"M",36.3230663928816,33.6,"0","0",NA
"M",42.652977412731,27.7,"0","0","3b"
"F",31.315537303217,23.1,"0","0","4"
"M",46.8528405201916,NA,"0","0",NA
"M",19.3949349760438,22,"0","0",NA
"F",26.4804928131417,25.9,"0","0","4"
"M",30.3107460643395,25.4,"0","0","4"
"F",30.2833675564682,24.7,"0","0",NA
"F",26.4804928131417,29.7,"0","0","4"
"F",46.3846680355921,28.8,"1","0","3b"
"F",32.9034907597536,32.7,"0","0","4"
"M",22.9103353867214,26.2,"0","0","4"
"M",35.2361396303901,26,"1","1","2"
"M",35.2361396303901,26,"1","1","2"
"M",53.6180698151951,21.3,"0","0",NA
"M",27.2470910335387,28.5,"0","1","5"
"M",27.2470910335387,28.5,"0","1","5"
"F",36.1998631074606,20.4,"0","0","3b"
"F",35.6221765913758,25.8,"1","0",NA
"M",57.3716632443532,21.5,"0","0","2"
"M",32.4134154688569,24.5,"0","0","2"
"M",20.2847364818617,28.2,"0","0","2"
"F",52.6023271731691,30.5,"1","0","4"
"F",33.5058179329227,21.6,"0","0",NA
"M",22.2532511978097,29.4,"0","0",NA
"M",49.8097193702943,22.9,"0","0","2"
"F",33.5085557837098,22.7,"0","0","5"
"F",41.3853524982888,32.7,"0","0","3b"
"M",52.9253935660507,29,"0","0","3a"
"M",54.0232717316906,25.2,"0","0","3a"
"F",57.9931553730322,17.4,"0","0","3a"
"F",36.5311430527036,22,"0","0",NA
"F",53.6235455167693,23.3,"0","0","3a"
"M",46.7679671457906,25.5,"0","0","3a"
"M",51.4387405886379,34,"0","0","3a"
"M",57.2539356605065,20.4,"0","0","4"
"M",28.331279945243,24.8,"0","0","2"
"F",22.3928815879535,19.6,"0","0","3b"
"M",52.0355920602327,28.3,"0","0",NA
"M",39.4387405886379,19.4,"0","0","4"
"F",35.7618069815195,27.9,"0","0","3b"
"M",34.5516769336071,30.9,"0","0","3a"
"F",36.2765229295003,29.4,"1","0",NA
"M",38.6173853524983,27.4,"0","0","3a"
"F",50.9596167008898,24.2,"0","0",NA
"M",21.6509240246407,28.4,"0","0","3b"
"F",46.8966461327858,22.1,"0","0","3b"
"F",56.1998631074606,30.8,"0","0",NA
"F",53.5496235455168,24.2,"0","0",NA
"M",23.9260780287474,15.2,"0","0","3b"
"M",59.0800821355236,22,"0","0","4"
"F",50.7022587268994,61.7,"0","0","4"
"M",27.4223134839151,22.1,"0","0","4"
"M",43.192334017796,24.9,"0","0","3b"
"M",53.5468856947296,29.3,"0","0","3b"
"M",63.4086242299795,25.7,"0","0",NA
"M",47.0417522245038,25.5,"0","0","4"
"M",45.1937029431896,30.3,"0","0","3a"
"M",31.4661190965092,25.3,"0","0","4"
"F",47.4661190965092,35.4,"0","0",NA
"F",44.9555099247091,34.6,"0","0",NA
"F",54.9760438056126,29.6,"0","0",NA
"M",45.6892539356605,29.1,"0","0","2"
"M",50.0917180013689,26.8,"0","0","3b"
"F",31.895961670089,25.9,"0","0","3b"
"M",61.7248459958932,25.9,"0","0","4"
"M",24.5749486652977,38.3,"0","0","3a"
"M",48.3148528405202,39.8,"0","0","5"
"F",50.3819301848049,32.4,"0","0","3a"
"F",58.2943189596167,35.3,"0","0","3b"
"F",28.2765229295003,24.6,"0","1","3b"
"F",28.2765229295003,24.6,"0","1","3b"
"F",24.6954140999316,21.1,"0","0","2"
"F",23.4223134839151,17,"1","0","3a"
"M",42.7214236824093,26.3,"0","0","3b"
"M",54.6365503080082,27.8,"0","0","3b"
"M",32.7200547570157,32.5,"0","0","3b"
"M",32.0684462696783,23,"0","0","4"
"M",44.8542094455852,30.1,"0","0",NA
"M",36.5886379192334,29.5,"0","0","2"
"F",39.5154004106776,27.7,"0","0","3b"
"M",49.015742642026,22.4,"1","0","4"
"M",35.6796714579055,31.6,"0","0",NA
"F",33.6810403832991,35,"0","0","3b"
"F",30.5270362765229,28,"0","0","2"
"M",57.5797399041752,24.2,"0","0","3a"
"M",50.2751540041068,24.7,"0","0","3a"
"F",63.0636550308008,28.5,"0","0","3a"
"M",52.8186173853525,25.9,"0","0",NA
"F",58.5927446954141,24.4,"0","0","3b"
"M",57.5605749486653,24.1,"0","0","3a"
"F",60.7173169062286,24.6,"0","0","3b"
"F",56.2354551676934,31.4,"0","0","4"
"M",71.586584531143,22.8,"0","0","3b"
"M",56.1806981519507,22.1,"0","0","3b"
"M",45.1362080766598,33.8,"0","0","4"
"F",43.4907597535934,18.9,"0","0","3b"
"M",27.9698836413415,32.4,"0","0",NA
"M",21.2731006160164,24.2,"0","0",NA
"M",46.7898699520876,33.1,"0","0","3a"
"F",37.2292950034223,22.1,"0","0",NA
"M",44.3504449007529,37.4,"0","0","3b"
"M",53.5770020533881,30.5,"0","0","4"
"M",30.1601642710472,26.8,"0","0","3a"
"M",39.2991101984942,40.6,"0","0","3a"
"F",26.0917180013689,26.7,"1","0","3a"
"M",60.3285420944559,32.7,"0","0","4"
"F",64.0739219712526,25.8,"1","0",NA
"F",47.4852840520192,36.4,"0","0","4"
"F",47.6358658453114,43.3,"1","0","4"
"M",47.3921971252567,31.8,"0","0","3a"
"F",41.5906913073238,18.1,"0","0","2"
"M",46.6228610540726,36.6,"0","0","4"
"F",57.8918548939083,30.3,"0","0","3b"
"M",57.1964407939767,27.8,"0","0","4"
"M",31.2361396303901,26.6,"0","0","3b"
"F",57.8754277891855,29.1,"0","0","3b"
"M",38.0342231348392,27.9,"0","0",NA
"M",29.1416837782341,23.6,"0","0",NA
"M",44.8761122518823,28.9,"0","0","2"
"F",47.2169746748802,30.4,"1","0","3b"
"M",39.5920602327173,28.4,"0","0",NA
"M",46.7926078028747,29.8,"0","0","2"
"M",28.249144421629,59.5,"0","0","1"
"M",46.0533880903491,29.4,"0","0",NA
"F",63.5619438740589,28.3,"0","0","4"
"F",59.4852840520192,40.4,"0","0","3b"
"M",34.9459274469541,24.5,"0","0","3a"
"M",48.0739219712526,21.8,"1","0","4"
"F",55.8932238193018,25.3,"0","0","3b"
"F",36.7611225188227,22.3,"0","0","3b"
"M",45.1143052703628,25.8,"0","0","2"
"F",35.9151266255989,26.3,"0","0",NA
"M",57.4976043805613,27.4,"0","0","3b"
"F",57.5496235455168,23,"0","0","3b"
"F",59.2279260780287,25.9,"0","0","3a"
"M",58.4010951403149,30,"0","0",NA
"F",36.1697467488022,30.3,"0","0","3b"
"M",51.0006844626968,24.1,"1","0","4"
"M",63.564681724846,31.7,"0","0","3b"
"M",44.9555099247091,25.8,"0","0","3a"
"F",46.943189596167,47,"0","0","2"
"M",44.7063655030801,27.5,"0","0","2"
"M",35.192334017796,26,"1","0","1"
"M",63.1101984941821,24,"0","0",NA
"F",53.864476386037,32,"0","0","3b"
"M",41.9110198494182,20.5,"0","1","2"
"M",41.9110198494182,20.5,"0","1","2"
"F",62.9185489390828,30.4,"0","0","3b"
"M",54.2203969883641,21.1,"1","0","2"
"M",46.9404517453799,25.5,"0","0","3a"
"F",64.4736481861738,31.2,"0","0","3a"
"M",57.927446954141,33,"0","0",NA
"M",43.8247775496235,30.6,"0","0","4"
"F",34.0889801505818,25.7,"0","0","2"
"M",51.0499657768652,28.9,"1","0","2"
"M",32.974674880219,36.3,"1","0","3a"
"F",57.8179329226557,21.4,"0","1",NA
"F",57.8179329226557,21.4,"0","1",NA
"F",61.0841889117043,21.2,"0","0","3b"
"M",48.3340177960301,22.5,"0","0","3b"
"F",48.0985626283368,26.3,"0","0",NA
"F",54.2012320328542,36.7,"0","0","3b"
"M",59.2854209445585,31.8,"0","0","3b"
"M",40.7310061601643,31.6,"0","1",NA
"M",40.7310061601643,31.6,"0","1",NA
"M",60.8980150581793,29.9,"0","0",NA
"M",49.8316221765914,26.3,"0","0",NA
"M",26.3052703627652,19.1,"0","1","3b"
"M",26.3052703627652,19.1,"0","1","3b"
"M",35.937029431896,31.1,"0","0",NA
"M",60.4654346338125,28.4,"0","0","4"
"F",37.347022587269,21.5,"0","0","3b"
"F",66.880219028063,25.9,"0","0",NA
"M",41.3114305270363,34.8,"0","0","3a"
"M",69.7084188911704,31.3,"0","0",NA
"M",61.5660506502396,25.1,"1","0","4"
"F",54.9733059548255,23.8,"1","0","3b"
"M",59.2662559890486,35.1,"0","0","3b"
"M",41.6180698151951,28.1,"0","0","3b"
"F",47.6988364134155,29.2,"0","0",NA
"M",49.719370294319,37.4,"0","0","3a"
"F",57.3442847364819,25,"0","0","4"
"F",41.6591375770021,26.7,"0","0",NA
"M",43.6933607118412,27.5,"1","0","3b"
```

And the code:

```
factor_columns <- c("factor1", "factor2", "CKD_stage", "rcp_sex")
data <- data %>% 
  mutate_at(factor_columns, as.factor)
```

One of the issues (but not the only one) I encountered is with this piece of code:

```
ggplot(aes(x = age, y = factor1)) +    geom_point() +   stat_smooth(method="glm", se=FALSE, method.args = list(family=binomial))
```

Similar problem is encountered when using function getDescriptionStatsBy from Gmisc package, when it then gives proportions as a sum of "ones" (that are actually "zeroes" in the original coding).

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible code on how you generate your dataframe ?

Comment: Factors are stored internally as integers starting with 1. Your levels are still "0" and "1", as it shows in your screenshot. You can verify this with `levels()`. This is expected and is not a problem. Logistic regression will treat them properly. Try it and see: `y = factor(rep(0:1, 10)); x = rnorm(20); glm(y ~ x, family = binomial)` works fine.

Comment: In fact, any factor with 2 levels will work fine for logistic regression: define `y12 = rep(1:2, 10)` and `glm(y12 ~ x, family = binomial)` still works fine (using my `x` above). If you're having a logistic regression error about the response being between 1 and 2 you must have accidentally converted your factor back to integer/numeric, and that is causing the problem. If you do want to go back to integer/numeric, make sure to use `as.integer(as.character(your_factor))` because using `as.integer` or `as.numeric` directly will give the internal integer storage, not the levels.

Comment: @GregorThomas

Thank you. I agree, logistic regression works fine by itself. But there are issues described when I tried to incorporate it within ggplot:

  `ggplot(aes(x = age, y = factor1)) + 
  geom_point() +
  stat_smooth(method="glm", se=FALSE, method.args = list(family=binomial))`

Then I got the y has to be between 0 and 1 error.

Comment: Put the code that causes the error in the question! Don't hide the problem in the comments!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `ggplot`, `stat_smooth`, we need a continuous axis, which means not a factor. From the examples in the `?geom_smooth` documentation:

> `# To fit a logistic regression, you need to coerce the values to`
>
> `# a numeric vector lying between 0 and 1.`
>
> `ggplot(rpart::kyphosis, aes(Age, as.numeric(Kyphosis) - 1)) +`
>
> `...`

Following these instructions (this process would be the same no matter what your factor levels are, as long as there are 2 levels):

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = age, y = as.numeric(factor1) - 1)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  stat_smooth(method="glm", se=FALSE, method.args = list(family=binomial))
```

[image]

Your problem is not with the `factor`, but with the subsequent methods. If you have more problems, I'd encourage you to ask more questions illustrating those problems. But probably this similar technique will work--binary data can be left as integer 1s and 0s, there's often no reason to convert such columns to factors at all, and many methods that expect binary data may not expect factors.